# Which is faster: Array list or looping through all data combinations?

Tags: java, performance, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays, memory-pool

I'm programming something in Java, for context see this question: [Markov Model descision process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364246/markov-model-descision-process-in-java)

I have two options:

```
byte[MAX][4] mypatterns;
```

or
    ArrayList mypatterns

I can use a Java ArrayList and append a new arrays whenever I create them, or use a static array by calculating all possible data combinations, then looping through to see which indexes are 'on or off'.

Essentially, I'm wondering if I should allocate a large block that may contain uninitialized values, or use the dynamic array.

I'm running in fps, so looping through 200 elements every frame could be very slow, especially because I will have multiple instances of this loop.

Based on theory and what I have heard, dynamic arrays are very inefficient

My question is: Would looping through an array of say, 200 elements be faster than appending an object to a dynamic array?

Edit>>>

More information:

- I will know the maxlength of the array, if it is static.
- The items in the array will frequently change, but their sizes are constant, therefore I can easily change them.
- Allocating it statically will be the likeness of a memory pool
- Other instances may have more or less of the data initialized than others

Comment: By dynamic array, are you referring to a `List`, such as an `ArrayList`? What theory and where have you heard that `ArrayList` is very inefficient compared to a plain array? It is not.

Comment: Yes, and I was just editing it.

Comment: ArrayList may not be inefficient I suppose, but what I've heard is static arrays are many times faster. Not sure if that's true, but that's what I understand.

Comment: While normally an ArrayList is unavoidable, in this case I could actually choose, which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are keeping a running window for computing through a time series or something alike. If that's the case I recommend a circular buffer.

Comment: It is unlikely that any performance issues you may have is caused by using `ArrayList` instead of a plain array. Don't complicate your code for this, unless a Profiler shows you that the `ArrayList` is causing performance degradation.

Comment: If @AlexSuo is right, and you're using a circular buffer, you should use an `ArrayDeque`. It's very efficient for that purpose.

Comment: @AlexSuo Essentially yes, but I'm more concerned about how to store the results. As for the actual window, I was just going to use a stack.

Comment: A static stack that is.

Comment: @Andreas You right really, I should use a profiler first, but I'm also just curious about the question 'in theory'

Comment: Actually, if you take a look at the api for `Stack` it says: "A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class."

Comment: @azurefrog Haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: @azurefrog Those classes look like they are designed for dynamic stacks, mine is a static length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You right really, I should use a profiler first, but I'm also just curious about the question 'in theory'.

The "theory" is too complicated.  There are too many alternatives (different ways to implement this) to analyse.  On top of that, the actual performance for each alternative will depend on the the hardware, JIT compiler, the dimensions of the data structure, and the access and update patterns in your (real) application on (real) inputs.

And the chances are that **it really doesn't matter**.

In short, nobody can give you an answer that is *well founded* in theory.  The best we can give is recommendations that are based on intuition about performance, and / or based on software engineering common sense:

- simpler code is easier to write and to maintain,
- a compiler is a more consistent<sup>1</sup> optimizer than a human being,
- time spent on optimizing code that doesn't need to be optimized is wasted time.

---

<sup>1 - Certainly over a large code-base.  Given enough time and patience, human can do a better job for some problems, but that is not sustainable over a large code-base and it doesn't take account of the facts that 1) compilers are always being improved, 2) optimal code can depend on things that a human cannot take into account, and 3) a compiler doesn't get tired and make mistakes.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Any performance difference will not be visible, when you set `initialCapacity` on `ArrayList`. You say that your collection's size can never change, but what if this logic changes?
Using `ArrayList` you get access to a lot of methods such as `contains`.

As other people have said already, use `ArrayList` unless performance benchmarks say it is a bottle neck.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to iterate over bytes is as a single arrays.  A faster way to process these are as `int` or `long` types as process 4-8 bytes at a time is faster than process one byte at a time, however it rather depends on what you are doing.  Note: a byte[4] is actually 24 bytes on a 64-bit JVM which means you are not making efficient use of your CPU cache.  If you don't know the exact size you need you might be better off creating a buffer larger than you need even if you are not using all the buffer. i.e. in the case of the byte[][] you are using 6x time the memory you really need already.

Comment: Do you mean the byte size, or the number of bytes? I thought memory alignment occurred in multiples  of 8 in Java?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer The default memory alignment for objects is 8 bytes. However if you want a compact and efficient data structure you want a byte[] or similar for all the data so that each byte only uses byte.

Comment: Oh I see, I guess I could do that and loop through with i+=4 or something.